# Как вытащить список из строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка со списком:

```py
a = '[<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>]'
```

Как из этого сделать список?
Тоесть чтоб

```py
а == [<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>]
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто создайте пустой список и занесите эту строку в него.

```
a = '[<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>]'

b = []
b.append(a)
```

Comment: А если теперь попробовать посмотреть на результат `print b` ?

Comment: выведет [<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>]

Comment: или все же -- `['[<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>]']`?

Comment: Нет, выведет [<telebot.types.LabeledPrice object at 0x7fe76a0994a8>], по крайней мере у меня так.

Comment: @Corrygan предложенный вами код не может вывести такое

Comment: Ну как это, я протестил его, он работает. Вот скриншот консоли https://imgur.com/a/JyHktQp